# Form not rendering on Second Submit AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have an HTML form that is trigged with AJAX to submit using a Rails backend. However, after submitting the first time, the form stops submitting. From reading other posts, I realize part of the problem is that the issue is related to including $(document) and not the form submit handler in the JQUERY call, but changing it to something like $('.new_todo form').submit will return the page as a JSON object instead of just the instantiated object {} response that I get with using $(document) in the Jquery.

I'm essentially trying to create an object and then to keep appending it to the index page, which works on the first submit, but as noted not on subsequent ones.

I'd really appreciate any insight because I've been staring at this for hours and while tons of answers address similar challenges (unbinding etc), nothing I found successfully addresses this use case.

The current AJAX call is:

```
 $(document).on('submit', '.new_todo', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/todos",
    data: {
      'authenticity_token': $("input[name='authenticity_token']").val(),
      'todo': {
        'name': $("#todo_name").val()
      }
    },
    success: function(response) {
      $("#todo_name").val("")
      $("#todo_location").html("")
      $("#todo_date").html("")
      let newTodo = new Todo(response)
      let todoHtml = newTodo.formatIndex()
      $('.todo-list').append(todoHtml)
    }
  })
})
```

The controller action for my create is:

```
 def create
   @todo = Todo.new(todo_params)
   @todo.save
   render json: @todo
 end
```

Thank you!!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `document` in `$(document).on('submit', '.new_todo', (e)z` should be on the class/id of the form tag.

Comment: i got it working. i had to add return false as well.